# Задача с ACMP с неверным решением C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=293):

> В некотором государстве действует N фирм, конкурирующих между собой. У каждой фирмы есть некоторая прибыль в год, равная V[i] американских рублей. У царя есть любимые фирмы, а есть нелюбимые. Соответственно, налог для всех фирм разный и назначается царем в индивидуальном порядке. Налог на i-ую фирму равен p[i] процентов.

> Собиратели статистики решили посчитать, с какой фирмы в государственную казну идет наибольший доход (в казну идут все налоги). К сожалению, они не учили в детстве ни математику, ни информатику (так что учитесь, дети!), и их задача резко осложняется.

> **Входные данные**
> Во входном файле INPUT.TXT сначала записано число N - число фирм (0 < N ≤ 100). Далее идет N целых неотрицательных чисел, не превышающих 154 - доходы фирм, а затем еще N целых чисел от 0 до 100 - налоги фирм в процентах.

> **Выходные данные**
> В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите одно число - номер фирмы, от которой государство получает наибольший налог. Если таких фирм несколько, выведите фирму с наименьшим номером.

Что по сути надо сделать? Вывести индекс максимального элемента, который равен `a * (b/100)`.

Первое, что можно сделать: допустим мы выстроили прибыль по возрастанию.

```
a_1 * (b_1/100) < a_2 * (b_2/100) < ... < a_n * (b_n/100) | *100 (домножим на 100 данное неравенство)

a_1 * b_1 < a_2 * b_2 < a_3 * b_3 < ... < a_n * b_n
```

Таким образом, нам надо найти индекс n такой, что `a_n * b_n = max(a_1 * b_1, a_2 * b_2, ... , a_n * b_n)`, и тогда даже переменные с плавающей точкой не придется использовать.

Мое решение:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    int mxcnt = -1; //переменная для записи максимального значения a_k * b_k
    int id = -1; //запись индекса для этого значения.
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        if (a * b > mxcnt)
        {
            mxcnt = a*b;
            id = i+1;
        }
    }
    cout << id;
}
```

Но в одних из начальных тестов, мое решение дает неверный ответ. В чем может быть проблема? Моя идея сама по себе неверная? Или программа спотыкается на каких-то частных случаях?

Comment: Что значит неверный результат??? Исходные данные и полученные результаты предоставьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Durdma если бы у меня были тесты, я бы скорее всего сюда бы не писал. acmp их не предоставляет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что идут не попарно "доход-процент", а сначала серия доходов, потом серия процентов - перечитайте условие...

Так что полное решение на С++ для ACMP (они же любят покороче :)) -

```
#include <iostream>
int v[100],n,m=-1,i,j,d;
#define x std::cin>>
main()
{
    x n;
    for(; i < n; x v[i++]);
    for(; x n; )
        if((n*=v[j++]) > m) m=n,d=j;
    std::cout << d;
}
```